# How does Spring wire method parameters?

Tags: spring

I have this Spring method which just maps a resource onto a .jsp :

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "display")
public String displayResult() {

  return "mypage"

}
```

If I update the method to :

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "display")
public String displayResult(javax.portlet.ResourceResponse rr) {

  rr.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");    
  return "mypage"

}
```

the variable rr is initialised but what Spring "magic" is occurring in the background to initialise the object javax.portlet.ResourceResponse ?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the Spring MVC framework. The default rules are explained in the section "Defining @RequestMapping handler methods" of the Spring documentation ([Link for 3.2.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods))

My guess is that you have a helper library on your classpath which extends the defaults for the annotation `@ResourceMapping` and the type `ResourceResponse`

Comment: I don't think there is any extension of the @ResourceMapping annotation in my source code. Where could I begin to search for extensions to this annotation ?

Comment: Use your IDE to find all places where the type is used.

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron pointed out, there default rules for resolving arguments for handler methods explained in a link he provided.

However, making a handler method accept other types of parameters is achieved not by extending @ResourceMapping annotation, but by implementing new  WebArgumentResolver prior to Spring 3.1 and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver from 3.1. See  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html

In your case, javax.portlet.ResourceResponse is probably directly supported by the Spring web mvc portlet framework, though I couldn't find a documentation for this. In your IDE, you can have a look at all classes implementing HandlerMethodArgumentResolver (or WebArgumentResolver)